# Cancel panel opening from toolbar widget onClick handler

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a Firefox extension which adds a toolbar Widget with a panel which should display when the widget is clicked. Under certain circumstances, the panel should not show when the toolbar widget is clicked.

I am instantiating the toolbar and panel like so:

```js
var popup = panel.Panel({
  width: 310,
  height: 400,
  contentURL: self.data.url('panel.html'),
  contentScriptFile: self.data.url('panel.js'),
  // NOTE: You can't use the contentStyleFile option here.
});

var toolbarOptions = {
  id: 'someid',
  label: 'Some Label',
  contentURL: self.data.url('icon-16.png'),
  panel: popup
};

// There doesn't seem to be a way to remove the toolbar in PB mode.
var toolbar = widgets.Widget(toolbarOptions);
```

How can I cancel the panel opening from the widget click handler? It seems to always open no matter what logic I put in there.

```js
toolbar.on('click', function() {
  if (dontShowPanel()){
    // I want to somehow cancel the panel opening at this point.
  } else {
    panel.show();
  }
});
```

I have tried to `return false;` from the click hander which doesn't seem to work. I have also tried to call `panel.hide()`. That doesn't seem to work either.

I'm using version 1.10 of the add-on SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `click` event handler is called before the panel shows up which means that you can still change the panel at this point. However, something that is non-obvious: changing the panel of the `Widget` object won't have any immediate effect, you need to change it for the `WidgetView` object (the widget instance in the particular browser window). That object is being passed as a parameter to the `click` event handler. So your toolbar options could look like this:

```js
var toolbarOptions = {
  id: 'someid',
  label: 'Some Label',
  contentURL: self.data.url('icon-16.png'),
  onClick: function(view) {
    if (dontShowPanel()){
      view.panel = null;
    } else {
      view.panel = popup;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create the widget, you need to add the panel instance as a property:

```
var panel = require("panel").Panel({
  width: 250,
  height: 250,
  contentURL: data.url('panel.html')
});

require("widget").Widget({
    id: 'id',
    label: 'my-label',
    contentURL: data.url('http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico'),
    panel: panel
});
```

Update: sorry I didn't understand the entire question. As far as I know there is no way to conditionally prevent show the panel based on the click event, in a way that will preserve the anchoring.

Comment: Yep that's what I am doing (I added my widget creation code to the question). That makes the panel show up perfectly, no problem. What I'd like is to be able to add a panel like that but then conditionally not show it when the user clicks on the widget depending on the circumstances at the time.